# Problem with restriction in xsd

Tags: xsd

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:any">
```

Why cant I put restriction on any type like this?

Comment: please provide an example of any more specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its meaningless, semantically it would be like the statment "You can't do nothing"

More syntactically, after reading about [xs:restriction](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_restriction.asp), I think that [xs:any](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_complex_any.asp) is not a built in data type, simpleType element or a complexType element but rather a place holder for extending a document with any element.

Comment: then how to simulate this:
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:any">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:restriction>

Comment: @Dominating, <xsd:sequence> <xsd:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> </xsd:sequence> has the same meaning.

Comment: @Jordell: Having a base type that allows anything is actually *the least restricting* starting point possible for a restriction. What is *inside* the `<xs:restriction>` is the thing that could forbid all different contents.

Comment: @Jasso, I understand that, as I said its meaningless, it would in fact be no restriction at all. Apologies if my answer was in some way ambiguous. `xs:any` is not limited to types.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put such restriction, because `xs:any` is not a type.

If you want to derive a new type by restriction and you want the base type to be just anything (elements or text) then use `<xs:restriction base="xs:anyType">`. If you are defining a simple type (text only), you can also use `<xs:restriction base="xs:anySimpleType">`